# $(x+2)\cos\frac1{x+2} - x\cos\frac1x > 2$ for $x\in[1,\infty)$

Tags: calculus

Let $$f(x) = x\cos\frac{1}{x}$$ for x in $[1,\infty)$

Now I need to prove or disprove the difference $$f(x+2) - f(x) > 2$$ for all $x$ in the domain.

I tried a lot but I don't seem to be getting anywhere. My approach was to try and use graphs, but somehow that doesn't seem to work out that well.

Any ideas or suggestions please?

Comment: My first inclination would be to find a bound for $f'$ and using the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: Indeed,   $f''(x)=-(1/x^3)\cos(1/x)<0$ for $x>1$. So, the first derivative is decreasing on $[1,\infty)$.  But $f'(x)=\cos(1/x)+(1/x)\sin(1/x)$ has limit $1$ at infinity, and $f'(1)>1$. So $f'(x)>1$ for $x\in[1,\infty)$. The Mean Value Theorem then gives the result.

Comment: Yeah that seems to work out. And I guess that's what Abel's solution demonstrates

Answer (score 3):

Note that cosine function is strictly concave on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\supset[0,1]$. It implies that when $x\ge 1$,
$$\frac{2}{x+2}\cos 0 +\frac{x}{x+2}\cos\frac{1}{x} < \cos\left(\frac{2}{x+2}\cdot 0+\frac{x}{x+2}\cdot \frac{1}{x}\right)=\cos\frac{1}{x+2}.$$
The conclusion follows.

Comment: That seems to be ingenious, but could you explain your motivation behind this? What exactly made you think in this direction?

Comment: @Quark: It was suggested by the statement of your question itself. Firstly I noticed only one function($\cos$) was involved in your inequality and the coefficient $x+2$ was just the sum of  $x$ and $2$, so I suspected the inequality was related to convexity/concavity. Then I rewrote the inequality as $\cos\frac{1}{x+2}>\frac{x}{x+2}\cos\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{x+2}$,  compared it with $f(tu+(1-t)v)>tf(u)+(1-t)f(v)$, and found that $1$ could be expressed as $\cos 0$ and $\cos$ is strictly concave on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Comment: @Quark: Please note that since $\cos$ is strictly concave on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, the same argument is still valid when $\frac{1}{x}\le \frac{\pi}{2}$, as shown in Abel's answer.

Comment: Great! I guess rewriting the inequality was kind of hard....

Answer (score 2):

Hint: When $x\ge 1$, then $0 \lt \frac 1x \le 1$.  How does $\cos y$ behave when $0\lt y\le 1$?

Comment: It is a decreasing function with values between cos1 and 1. By that we can say the given expression is always greater than zero, but how do we prove it's greater than 2...

Answer (score 1):

For an alternative approach consider $g(y) = \cos(y)+y\sin(y)$.
$$g^\prime(y) = -\sin(y)+\sin(y)+y\cos(y) = y\cos(y) >0$$ for $y\in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. Thus
$$g(y) > g(0) = \cos(0)+0\sin(0) = 1$$ for $y\in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$.

Now calculate $f^\prime(x) = \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$. By the previous paragraph, $f^\prime(x)>1$ for $\frac{1}{x}\in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ or equivalently $x\geq\frac{2}{\pi}$.

Hence, we conclude $\displaystyle f(x+2)-f(x) = \int_x^{x+2} f^\prime(y)\,\mathrm{d}y > \int_x^{x+2} 1\,\mathrm{d}y = 2$ for all $x\geq\frac{2}{\pi}$.